# Material Drawer opens automatically as activity starts

Tags: android, materialdrawer

When I use Material Drawer, as soon as a new activity starts, drawer is being displayed automatically, but I want that it starts hidden, so I have to use function **drawer.closeDrawer()** in the method **onResume** of activity, as described below:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    drawer.closeDrawer();
}
```

Is this the correct way to hidden the drawer when activity starts or restarts, or there is a property to be set for this purpose in the drawer?

Thank you,
Alexandre Bianchi

Comment: It's not. Where is your drawer code?

Comment: Check you are not opening the drawer in your initialisation of the drawer. This is likely if you are following the dev guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in oncreate and it will check the drawer is open or not...if its open it will close the drawer

```
    DrawerLayout layout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
         if (layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
             layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
```

Comment: this does the same as `drawer.closeDrawer();` mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1):

There are different cases why the drawer may opens after the application starts.

Either you define `withShowDrawerOnFirstLaunch`, this should be removed or set to false, if you don't want this behavior. 
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/DrawerBuilder.java#L1188

It could also be that you open the drawer via the `Drawer`'s API. So make sure you don't call `openDrawer` programtically
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/Drawer.java#L125

The `Drawer` comes also with a method to `close` the drawer. Just call `closeDrawer` 
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/Drawer.java#L134